# I can't use wifi driver with Secure boot enabled

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, secure-boot

how are you, community.
Today, I've got installing Ubuntu 20.04 and all is working fine, except that I can't use the Wifi adapter. The software manager says I have installed it. I have enabled Secure Boot and doesn't work with it, so I disabled it and the wifi driver works. If I must use Ubuntu with SecureBoot disabled, how can it affect Windows OS (I use DualBoot)? Is there any solution, or any way for delete the "Booting in insecure mode" message when booting? My PC is a HP Pavilion 15-cw1004. Thank you so much.[image: Software and update manager]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling “Secure Boot” should not be seen as making you computer less secure, because it’s not. “Secure Boot” is Microsoft-speak for *ensuring people use Windows as their OS*. It’s just a means of artificial vendor lock in. Ubuntu — and many other Linux distributions — are incredibly secure by default.

1. Disable “Secure Boot”
2. Use your computer
3. Get on with your day

Comment: Ok. I get it. Thank you so much 

Comment: When I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo it instructed me to use secure boot (I believe it implied some of my hardware required it).  In that case am I just out of luck on wifi?