Re-Enabling Secure Boot after driver update caused error for Ubuntu dual boot on mac after upgrading ubuntu to 24.4.1
I have a dual boot system set up on my Mac mini 2018 (intel core) use refind to boot both mac and Ubuntu. I had Ubuntu 22.04 jammy jellyfish installed, and I just upgraded to the new 24.4.1 LTS Noble Numbat. The upgrade went fine, but my wifi driver stopped working. So I went through the same steps I had done before to reinstall the driver and firmware, using this guide: Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers. Basically, I just installed "bcmwl-kernel-source" but I had to disable Secure Boot to make it work.
So now my wifi works fine, but when I re-enabled secure boot via recovery mode, I can't boot Ubuntu anymore. Refind appears to be working fine, but when I select my Ubuntu boot, I get the error: "unable to verify startup disk". (The Mac OS still boots fine with Secure Boot enabled.) I've read in numerous threads that an issue like this can happen if i did not have secure boot enabled when I installed Ubuntu, but I did have it enabled (i only disabled it to install the driver, which for 22.04 didn't create this issue when I installed the driver).
I tried disabling secure boot again and that allows me to boot both Ubuntu and Mac just fine, but I don't feel comfortable leaving Secure boot off permanently b/c of the increased security exposure.
Is there a way to get my computer to recognize the Ubuntu OS with Secure Boot turned on? Plz let me know if I can post additional info that is of help.

Two simple alternatives: https://askubuntu.com/a/1304032/19626 , or (since this is not a laptop), prevent physical access to the device by guests.

Did you miss a step? To add a third party driver that is not signed will cause the driver not to run. To inhibit the Ubuntu boot  the drive would need to be part of the boot (which could be the case). When you first installed it into 22.04 (secure boot) did you go through an addition process of signing it with a local MOK key and then add the key to the UEFI during a special boot of Ubuntu?

Thank you for the responses. I did NOT set up a MOK key with ubuntu :(. I have not used a MOK management system before, but based on some googling it sounds like I can still add a MOK key for Ubuntu and/or the drivers I installed. Is that correct? Would you be able to provide some clarity on what steps I would need to take to do so? I have also read numerous comments online about the ease of not using secureboot, but as I understand it does protect from malware such as rootkits. It seems like its use varies in part due to a different in risk tolerance v. efficiency b/w ppl.
